# Update a value of a row on a grid with a CheckBox and Button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a gridview with checkboxes attached so an admin can approve of orders. He is given a list of orders and the ones he checks and leaves unchecked when the button is clicked it will update the approve field in the database.

checked - update to value in the approved field to -  **Approved**

Unchecked - update value in approved field to - **Disapproved**

However I am experiencing some difficulty:

**I have a grid with a check box:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewdoc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="Order Id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorId" HeaderText="Doctor Id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineId" HeaderText="Medicine Id" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="MedicineName" HeaderText="Medicine Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="pharmname" HeaderText="Pharmacy Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Dateordered" HeaderText="Date Ordered" />
    <asp:TemplateField> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
 <asp:CheckBox Text="Approve" ID="ApproveBox" runat="server" /> 
  </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

**It holds this select statement from the order table in my database:**

```
Create View docgridview 
As 

Select A.OrderID, A.DoctorId, B.Forename, B.Surname, A.MedicineId, C.Name as MedicineName, D.pharmname, A.Dateordered, Approved
From  order_pres  A
Left  Join Patient   B on (A.PatientId  = B.PatientId)
Left  Join Medicine  C on (A.MedicineId = C.MedicineId)
Left  Join pharmacy  D on (A.PharmacyId   = D.PharmacyId)
Left  Join Doctor    E on (A.DoctorId  = E.DoctorId)
```

**and binds it to a grid view like so** (select docgridview)

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmd3string As String = " Select * From docgridview  WHERE DoctorId = " & Session("DoctorId")
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd3string, conn)
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()



        GridViewdoc.DataSource = dt
        GridViewdoc.DataBind()
        HttpContext.Current.Session("Approved") = dt
    End If
```

**and this controls the checkboxes and button**:

```
Protected Sub GridViewdoc_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridViewdoc.RowDataBound


    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        CType(e.Row.FindControl("Approvebox"), CheckBox).Checked = True
    End If

End Sub
Protected Sub btnapprove_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnapprove.Click
    Dim dt As Data.DataTable = Session("Approved")
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewdoc.Rows
        Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("ApproveBox")
        If cb.checked Then
            dt.Rows(row.RowIndex).Item(8) = "Approved"
        Else
            dt.Rows(row.RowIndex).Item(8) = "Disapproved"
        End If
    Next
    GridViewdoc.DataSource = dt
    GridViewdoc.DataBind()
End Sub
```

**I am expereincing an error**:

[image]

for the checkboxes that are checked with the button.click - the 'Approved' column in the order table should change to the value **approved**

for the checkboxes that are UNchecked with the button.click - the 'Approved' column in the order table should change to the value **disapproved**.

This is the order table that will be updated (approved is set as bit and I am not sure if this is correct):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`[Order_pres].[Approved]` is a bit field and you are trying to set it to a string value. Just set it to `cb.checked`.

so instead of this:

```
 If cb.checked Then
      dt.Rows(row.RowIndex).Item(8) = "Approved"
 Else
      dt.Rows(row.RowIndex).Item(8) = "Disapproved"
 End If
```

do this:

```
dt.Rows(row.RowIndex).Item(8) = cb.checked
```

Comment: where do I set this to cb.checked? when I go through the different types of the field there is no cb.checked

Comment: but I want the values to update to approved if check and disapproved if not checked - this takes away those values

Comment: @laurajs, Approved or Disapproved is more appropriate as a boolean/bit than as a string. But if you really want "Approved" or "Disapproved" as the value, then you must change the data type in the database table like Zaid mentioned.

Comment: I would do it this way but this is the requirement of my assignment and when someone views the table they will see only the values that are approved in the next step I take

Comment: when I cheanged this data type and checked some boxes and uncheced others then clicked the button the gird appeared again with all of the check boxes checked and in the order table the approved column remained NULL

Comment: @laurajs, general practice is to format database values for display, not force your database into a UI format. Winforms has parse/format events exactly for this, not sure about webforms. But it is a mistake to use the wrong data types and try to do the binding conversions in this manner.

Comment: the same happened when I tested it with having the data type as bit and the values to true and false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117807/discussion-between-laurajs-and-crowcoder).

Answer (score 0):

Your  field is a bit, Which means it can take the value of either **True** or **false**. For your case you have 2 cases of action I can see fit:

1- Change type to nvarchar in database:
By changing type to nvarchar you have the freedom to set the value

2- Change the input to true or false, Then use VB.net to convert value from Boolean to Approved/Disapproved.

I recommend the 2nd action as it will keep your database untouched.

Comment: Hi Zaid! thankyou for your anser - but I dont know how to do the second one  - I cant find the type string?

Comment: I think it was nvarchar for SQL.

Comment: Hi Zaid - I changed the data type to this but after testing it   by leaving some of the orders cheched and some unchecked i clicked hte button the grid appeared again with the boxes recheched and I also checked the values in the database  the approved columns were all still NULL

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I don't really get what happened here.

Comment: Sorry Zaid . So I changed my datatype on the approved column to nvarchar and I went back into m webpage and tested - so I checked and unchecked some boxes then clicked th button and all of the boxes rechecked. I then went into my database to check if the orders I had checked and unchecked had updated but all remainded NULL

Comment: According to what I see from the code you are taking in values. This post here indicates you are trying to update values. (And thus a complete new sql statement for Update). Is that correct?

Comment: can u see the picture updated?
so
on the button click happens
the check boxes that are checked will update the approved fields in the row to approved
the ones that are not checked will update the approved fields in the row to disapproved

Comment: Your code updates a local Datatable (you can check that out by using break points) but you have no code to update the SQL server itself. What I used to do with OleDb (local databases) is using a new function with an Update query. You should look into making an update query after updating the datatable.